# What is the impact of writes to a cassandra cluster that is hosting analytics jobs?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I am considering a heavily analytics based spark cluster that also has to consume some writes from a response time sensitive UI.

Will the analytics jobs impact or hinder my rest response time ?

Will it have any other impact ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to keep multiple separate data centres. I couldn't find the blog about newest version of DSE but all the principles from the article still apply and the principles are applicable for the community cassandra too.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployWkLdSep.html